# Can passphrase be embedded into private key file?

Tags: ssh, passphrase

I have the some key file

```
----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
SOMEGARBAGECHARACTERS
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

but when I am trying to use it with ssh, it asks for some passphrase:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem myuser@myserver.amazonaws.com
Enter passphrase for key 'mykey.pem':
```

Is this just mean that inside this file some keyphrase is encoded? Or does mean something else?

**UPDATE**

No any DEK lines or something. Only homogeneous mass of random characters.

**UPDATE 2**

Key file was somehow corrupted. I received it by email and copypasted to text editor. There were no apparent differences but actually they were there. After I opened email with raw editor and copy/pasted key this way -- everythin worked.

As @Jakuje suggested, I used `openssl` tool and it reported an error.

Comment: Is there a "DEK-Info:" line at the top?

Comment: Some example keys, encoded versus un-encoded here.  http://serverfault.com/a/628980/984

Comment: The passphrase isn't within the private key, the passphrase is only in user memory, the passphrase protect the private key.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I swear I have no passphrase in my memory

Comment: Then, please describe how you created this (private key, public key) pair. The origin of the problem stands there.

Comment: Did you open your private key with a text editor (`vi`, `emacs`, `Word`, `TexteEdit`, `Pages`)? If yes, please consider the answer from @Jakuje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSH asks for passphrase for every garbage input. There is [open bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2522) for that upstream. It can be very confusing for a lot of users.

Only way to check what is behind that is to use openssl directly:

```
openssl rsa -text <mykey.pem
```

It should ask for a passphrase or report any other error in the key.

Answer (score 2):

It means the key itself was encrypted using a passphrase. To log in with the key, ssh first needs to decrypt it.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? There is no any DEK lines or something inside file.

Comment: In that case, see Jakuje's answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a private key, you can choose to protect it with a password. If you are 100% sure nobody (and no virus or anything) will ever copy that key, you can do without. Same if the key is for something that has no value like a local test machine with nothing of importance on it. Otherwise it's good practise to use a password.

If the private key is protected, the key is encrypted using that password, and you need to use the password to unlock the key. So it's normal that SSH asks for a password to use the key.